# ANDROID layout gets messed up from emulator to tablet

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, tablet

I've recently developed an android game using Eclipse. I'm really a newbie at this so forgive me if what I will ask is too simple. >.<

The application runs and looks perfectly in the Android emulator installed in Eclipse. However, when we tried to install it in a Samsung Galaxy tab which obviously has a bigger screen than the emulator, the layout gets messed up. Buttons are not in their right order etc. I do have screens using XML layouts and some are simple canvases with sprites. Any idea how I could retain the original layout in the emulator to the tablet? I've tried using `RelativeLayout` instead of `LinearLayout` but it still doesn't work.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

One XML file code and it's corresponding screen from emulator shown below.

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
style="@style/MenuLayout" >

<Button android:id="@+id/btnNew"
    android:layout_width="140px"
    android:layout_height="65px"
    android:layout_marginTop="160px"
    android:background="@drawable/newgame"/>
<Button android:id="@+id/btnInst"
    android:layout_width="140px"
    android:layout_height="65px"
    android:background="@drawable/instructions" />
<Button android:id="@+id/btnCredits"
    android:layout_width="140px"
    android:layout_height="65px"
    android:background="@drawable/credits"/>
<Button android:id="@+id/btnExit"
    android:layout_width="140px"
    android:layout_height="65px"
    android:background="@drawable/exit"/> </LinearLayout>
```

[image: corresponding image for xml above]

Comment: It'd certainly help if u posted some pics about this layout problem. And the layout files.

Comment: RelativeLayout should be used when you want something to display properly on any size screen. You should also make sure to use dip instead of pixels when setting dimensions.

Comment: Suggestion: you can also set a Samsung Galaxy tab emulator, see details here: [http://innovator.samsungmobile.com/galaxyTab.do] I'm sure your problem appears because you didn't correctly program for different screen sizes and densities(as using px), and not the emulator/device itself.

Comment: @Robby: Tried to use RelativeLayout in that screen but it just got messed up ie. exit appears first, then new game and the others doesn't show anymore.

Comment: Then you didn't do the layout properly with the above and below properties.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use dpi and not pixels.
Here's a good resource.
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, you should be using "dp" instead of "px". These are device independent pixels and will scale to match different screen resolutions.

You should also follow this [guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) on how to use a folder structure to support different screen resolutions and sizes.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Based on your edited question, and on the comments, here is a way to change your layout to a relative one:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     style="@style/MenuLayout"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <Button android:id="@+id/btnNew"
        android:layout_width="140dip"
        android:layout_height="65dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="160dip"
        android:background="@drawable/newgame" 
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
        android:layout_above="@+id/btnInst" />

    <Button android:id="@+id/btnInst"
        android:layout_width="140dip"
        android:layout_height="65dip"
        android:background="@drawable/instructions" 
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
        android:layout_above="@+id/btnCredits"/>

    <Button android:id="@+id/btnCredits"
        android:layout_width="140dip"
        android:layout_height="65dip"
        android:background="@drawable/credits"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
        android:layout_above="@+id/btnExit"/>

    <Button android:id="@+id/btnExit"
        android:layout_width="140dip"
        android:layout_height="65dip"
        android:background="@drawable/exit"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dip"/> 

</RelativeLayout>
```

Though, if you want a perfect solution, you need to design the buttons and background pictures in 3 sizes, and put them in the respective folders drawable-hdpi, drawable-mdpi and drawable-ldpi(and for tablets, from 2.2, you can also have drawable-xhdpi!). Read carefully this [article](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) and test your layout in emulator for as many screens as possible (from [ADT 10.0](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#) it is really easy to preview your layout for different configurations directly from Graphical Layout tab in xml).

Also, `android:layout_marginTop="160dip"` and `android:layout_marginBottom="25dip"` are not really useful in a Relative Layout. I would suggest you to try a [9-patch picture](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html) for your background, with only the wood board stretchable for the buttons (though I am not sure it's working like that). Alternatively, I would have a separate picture with *Main Menu*, that I'd place above the buttons, and keep in the background only the trees and everything else.

Answer (score 0):

itz better to provide diffrent layout for diffrent screen size . i also have same issue when developing a game.nw its done.
u may have provided layout ,so u just provide
layout-large,small,and xlarge.and vice verse to ur layouts u must provide drawable folders like hdpi,mdpi,ldpi,xdpi folders and u must save diffrent sized images 58*58,75*75,100*100 for following then u check it u will get it.